# What is the use of \romannumeral0?

Tags: counters

I understand \romannumeralk when k is positive. However, I have seen \romannumeral0 in a few codes but I do not understand its use. What is it?

Example:

```
\romannumeral0\expandafter\xintzapspaces\expandafter{\MAT_tmpa};!;%
```

this is line 28 of the code of the section ROW REDUCTION (INITIAL) ANSWER of this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360116/81269)

Comment: Can you show these "few codes," or at least an example of it?

Comment: I just did, thanks

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473621/4427 See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=romannumeral+trick

Comment: Thanks, @egreg. So the \numeral trick is no longer required because we have \expanded now. Correct? How \expanded can be used to modify the line of the example?

Comment: @Chilote `\expanded` is more powerful, but `\romannumeral` expansion may have its uses nonetheless.

Comment: Note that `\romannumeral0` is not safe, better would be `\romannumeral\`\^^@` instead, otherwise you might have issues with digits following the 0.